# page not get rendered using ajax in Jsf 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am facing very strange problem. After debugging from my side, I thought to post the same question on forum.

**Problem:** : I have 2 JSF Datatables say "TableA" and "TableB". I have some elements in TableB and now I want to move some articles based on criteria to move to TableA and get deleted or not visible in TableB.

I am able to add elements in TableA and can see that element has been deleted from TableB also through debugger as I printed the elements present in TableB but the same changes does not get reflected on UI.

**Code is:**

```
<div id="selectedTableId" class="ArtSlected">
<h:dataTable id="selectedArtTable" value="#{articleBean.artList1}" var="sel" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"
             cellpadding="0" columnClasses="center" class="TableStyle">
  <h:column>
    <h:commandButton id="deleteArticle" image="../resources/images/Delete.png" action="#{articleBean.deleteAction}">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{articleBean.articuloPromocionVO}" value="#{sel}"/>
      <f:ajax render=":articleSelectionForm:artDescTable selectedArtTable" execute="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.mpromo_article_selection_articles_selected}</f:facet>
    #{sel.articuloNombre} - #{sel.descripcion}
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</div>
```

Here, articleSelectionForm is the form name
artDescTable refers to TableA
selectedArtTable refers to TableB.

I have tried many combinations for the `<f:ajax>` tag, but nothing works out. Example,

```
<f:ajax render=":articleSelectionForm:artDescTable selectedArtTable" execute="@form" />
```

```
<f:ajax render=":articleSelectionForm:artDescTable :articleSelectionForm:selectedArtTable" execute="@form" />
```

```
<f:ajax render=":articleSelectionForm:artDescTable :articleSelectionForm:selectedTableId:selectedArtTable" execute="@form" />
```

Please tell me where I am wrong in understanding.

Comment: Do I read your code right that you have two forms?

Comment: Hi Matt, I have one form only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must refer the client ID of the component. For starters, the easiest way to figure the proper client ID is to open the page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* and locate the HTML representation of the JSF component. It'll look like this

```html
<table id="foo:bar:tableId" ...>
```

You need to take *exactly* this value and prefix it with `:`.

```html
<f:ajax render=":foo:bar:tableId" ... />
```

If it's not prefixed with `:`, the default [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) separator character, then it will be resolved relative to the current `NamingContainer` parent. Such components are `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<ui:repeat>`, composite components, etc.